# Finding an expression for ${a_n}$ for the series when $n > 1$

Tags: calculus

[image]

a.

When I solved for this problem, I first used the ${s_{n+1}} - {s_n} = {a_{n+1}}$ to solve for a number of nth terms in ${a_n}$. Using the series in ${a_n}$, I calculated that the closed formula for the series when n > 1 was $\frac{-109}{4n^2 + 40n + 99}$.

b.

For this part, I took the limit of ${a_n}$ to find the value, but first I took the constant out, giving me $\frac{1}{4n^2 + 40n + 99}$. Substituting in the infinity, I got $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$.

Both these answers were considered to be incorrect, but I'm not sure where I went wrong. Any kind of guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), you are following the correct procedure, although you have found $a_{n+1}$, not $a_n$ as asked for. Therefore, 
\begin{align}
a_n&=s_n-s_{n-1} \\
&=\frac{14-9n}{2n+9}-\frac{14-9(n-1)}{2(n-1)+9} \\
&=\frac{14-9n}{2n+9}- \frac{23-9n}{2n+7} \\
&=-\frac{109}{(2n+9)(2n+7)}.
\end{align}

Alternatively, you can replace $n$ with $n-1$ in your answer.

For part (b), by definition, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{14-9n}{2n+9}=-\frac{9}{2}.$$

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see, so mainly it was a matter of me using the wrong formula to start with. That's just frustrating lol. But I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

(a) You subtracted $s_{n+1}-s_n$ to get $a_{n+1}$, whereas the problem asked for $a_n$. Your indices are off.

(b) An infinite sum is the limit of the *partial sums*, not the *individual terms*.

Answer (score 0):

a) you had the right idea but I don't know if your math was good.  Let's see...

$s_{n} - s_{n-1} = a_n$ so $a_n = \frac{-9n + 14}{2n + 9} - \frac{-9(n-1) + 14}{2(n-1) +9}$... oh, god, that's *not* going to be pretty but I don't think your answer is  right.

b) Here a trick. You want to find $ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i$.  But you know the *partial* sum $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = s_n$.  So all you have to do is find $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$.

Comment: ...or maybe your answer will be right.  Other peoples answers seem to be similar to yours but with different indices.